# Vue 3 - [Vue warn]: Invalid vnode type when creating vnode

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I have the following code:

```html
 <script setup>
    
    import {ref, defineAsyncComponent, computed, reactive} from 'vue'
    import {useMainStore} from '@/store/main.js'
    import {useTableStore} from "@/store/tables";
    import DefaultLayout from '@/layouts/DefaultLayout.vue'
    import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'
    
    const tableStore = useTableStore()
    const { userData } = useMainStore()
    
    tableStore.getTables()
    
    const { freeTables, usedTables } = storeToRefs(useTableStore())
    
    const { tables } = storeToRefs(useTableStore())
    const loading = ref(false)
    
    const showOrder = ref(false)
    
    let props = reactive({
      orderID: null,
      id: null,
    })
    
    const tableOrderComponent = computed(() => showOrder.value ? defineAsyncComponent(() =>
        import("@/components/TableOrder.vue")) : ''
    )
    
    let tableOrder = (table) => {
      props.id = parseInt(table.id, 10)
      props.orderID = table.activeOrderID || null
    
      showOrder.value = true
    }
    </script>
    
    <template>
      <DefaultLayout>
        <template #default>
    
          <div class="row come-in">
            <div class="card col">
              <div class="card-header">
                <span class="text-capitalize"> {{ userData.username }}</span>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body subheader">
                Used Tables ({{ usedTables.length }})
              </div>
              <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                <li v-for="table in usedTables">
                  {{ table.name }}
                </li>
              </ul>
              <div class="card-body subheader">
                Free Tables ({{ freeTables.length }})
              </div>
              <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                <li v-for="table in freeTables">
                  {{ table.name }}
                  <a href="#" v-tooltip="'Add order to the table'" @click="tableOrder(table)">
                    <font-awesome-icon icon="fas fa-list-alt" />
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <table-order-component v-show="showOrder"
                  :orderID="props.orderID"
                  :id="props.id"></table-order-component>
            </div>
    
          </div>
        </template>
      </DefaultLayout>
    </template>
```

When the page is loaded I am getting following error (warning):

```
[vite] connecting... client.ts:16:8
[vite] connected. client.ts:53:14
[Vue warn]: Invalid vnode type when creating vnode: . 
  at <DefaultLayout> 
  at <Tables onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< undefined > > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <App> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:38:16
[Vue warn]: Invalid vnode type when creating vnode: . 
  at <DefaultLayout> 
  at <Tables onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< 
Proxy { <target>: Proxy, <handler>: {…} }
 > >    at <RouterView> at <App> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:38:16
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Default layout:

```
<script setup>
  import AppHeader from '@/components/AppHeader.vue'
</script>

<template>
  <AppHeader></AppHeader>
  <div id="container-fluid">

      <main>
        <slot></slot>
      </main>

  </div>

</template>
```

App Header:

```
<script setup>

import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'
import {useMainStore} from "@/store/main.js";

const mainStore = useMainStore()
const router = useRouter()

const logout = () => {
  mainStore.logout()
      .then(() => {
        router.push({
          name: 'Login'
        })
      })
}

</script>

<template>
  <nav id="nav">
    <button @click="logout">Logout</button>
  </nav>
</template>

<style>

</style>
```

Comment: Something in `DefaultLayout` seems wrong. Can you paste that component too?

Comment: @RizaKhan added the missing code.

Comment: I think the problem is the `table-order-component`. If you use `showOrder` you can define the component directly as async component without the computed value. I think, computed values cannot be used as components like this. You could also use `<component :is="…"`